# Bump into/against: The car bumped into/against a tree

Tags: prepositions, difference, word-difference

I don't know when to use **against** and when to use **into**, after bump:

> The cat bumped against the door
>
> The clumsy boy always bumps into the furniture
>
> While dancing, she bumped into me several times
>
> I ran after him, bumping against people in my hurry.

*Bump into* doesn't give me a headache when it means *meet by chance*, but it does only when it means physically hit by accident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two phrases are pretty much interchangeable, but certain situations might make the one or the other the more likely choice.

When you **bump into** something, there is usually some form of locomotion or lateral motion involved.

> She bruised her thigh when she bumped into the corner of the table.
>
> The dance floor was so crowded that the waltzing couples kept bumping into each other.

When something **bumps against** or **is bumping against** something else, there is usually no sense of locomotion, and the contact might be over a broader area.

> The subway car was so crowded and the car shook so much on the rails that the standing passengers kept bumping against each other.
>
> It was a tiny auto, and he was rather tall, so that his head bumped against the roof.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please expand on locomotion and lateral motion because the dictionary doesn't help me much to grasp the concept.

Comment: **Locomotion** is the act of moving yourself from one place to another, for example, across the room or from a chair over to a window.  Walking is a form of locomotion.

Comment: **lateral** refers to movements along a horizontal axis (not along a vertical axis)